# Protecting LocalDB database with password

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, localdb

LocalDB is a great move done by Microsoft, the needless of a database server and the portability of applications, however a user -after distributing the app- can open the database alone and see its schema and edit it :(

Is there an effective way to encrypt it with a password like "SQL Server CE" or "MS Access"?!

Comment: @SeanLange Of course I did, many times but none of them best fit...
Stack community is a good place to collect ideas and it is not a crime to duplicate ideas..
I think that stack moderators should review their rules

Comment: Well...go read the marked answer in the duplicated. It explains why this is not possible.

Comment: `LocalDB` is just a "on-demand" activated version of SQL Server **Express** and thus is still really a **server** - which you need to install in order to use - it's **NOT** an "embedded" database like SQL Server CE which works by just including a few DLL's in your application's `.\bin` directory ....